# how to correctly use touch listener/event and ease function in andEngine 

Tags: android, andengine, touch-event, tween

this touch event never fires. Ive been going through the examples and source codes and now am slightly confused on the best method of doing what i want.

I draw a sprite to the scene. I want that sprite to move with an EaseFunction to the coordinates of the users touch event.

this is the code so far:

```
private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private Camera mCamera;
private BitmapTextureAtlas mTexture;
private TextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;
// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
    this.mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(64, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/boxface.png", 0, 0);

    this.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    final int x = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int y = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    final Sprite face = new Sprite(x, y, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
    scene.attachChild(face);
    face.setPosition(134, 200);
```

//this is where I try to implement the touch listener and code//is it right?

```
    scene.setOnAreaTouchListener(new IOnAreaTouchListener() {
        //@Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX,float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                int facePosX = (int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - face.getWidth() / 2);
                int facePosY = (int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - face.getHeight() / 2);

                face.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(500, face.getX(), facePosX, face.getY(),facePosY,EaseQuadIn.getInstance())); 
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return scene;
}


@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {

}
```

finally im pretty sure i need to use pScene.registerTouchArea(face); and 
pScene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);

any clarification would be of great use.
thank you

Comment: i found the answer. but im new. so i have to wait 4 hours to answer my own post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works! just kept digging and found the answer here:http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/touchevent-t1490.html

here is the completed code. the sprite loads to the center of the page. where ever you click the sprite will 'tween' or ease to your touch coordinates.

```
package and.engine.test;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.MoveModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseQuadIn;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;



public class AndEnginetestActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private Camera mCamera;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mTexture;
    private TextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;
    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
        this.mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(64, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/boxface.png", 0, 0);

        this.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        final int x = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final int y = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
        final Sprite face = new Sprite(x, y, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
        scene.registerTouchArea(face);
        scene.attachChild(face);
        //face.setPosition(134, 200);

        scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
                int facePosX = (int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - face.getWidth() / 2);
                int facePosY = (int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - face.getHeight() / 2);
                 face.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(1, face.getX(), facePosX,face.getY(), facePosY, EaseQuadIn.getInstance()));               
                 return false;
            }
        });


        scene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);
        return scene;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {

    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================
}
```